# LuaLaTeX fails with package icomma and Font TeX Gyre Termes Math

Tags: unicode-math, compilation-error, icomma

I came across an error as shown in this minimal example. The code does not produce an error, but LuaLaTeX ends in a loop and must be killed.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{icomma}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \nabla  u,
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Since the `icomma` package is really old I wonder if its functionality was picked up by other packages?

Comment: Does `textualicomma` do what you need? Because this one still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both packages define `\mathcomma`, load `icomma` after `unicode-math`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}



\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}


\usepackage{icomma}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
  \nabla  u,
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to have proper spacing for the decimal separator, I'd suggest `siunitx`. It provides a `\num` command (among other things) that formats numbers properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num{2.1}

\end{document}
```

You can configure the use of a dot or a comma as a decimal separator (since this depends on your language), and so on. If you add:

```
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
```

to you preamble after loading the package, a comma will be used as a separator, even if you type a dot in the argument of `\num`.

And yes, the spacing around the comma will be tighter.

Comment: This is not a solution, because the comma is used as in f(x, y). The icomma package creates a space after the comma. Numbers with comma are a different problem.

Comment: OK, sorry for the confusion. `icomma`'s description is "Intelligent commas for decimal numbers", and `siunitx` matches that description. I wasn't aware that `icomma` had other uses.